# Get maxPoints for assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Is there a way to get the max points for an assignment in google classroom.  Example if an assignment is worth 25 points I want to find the "25" using appscripts.  I see where I can create an assignment and assign a maxPoints value. But, I want to retrieve it using appscripts

Searched the API

I do not have any code to show

Comment: At least show the code you've written to look at assignments. Are you looking at a single student's multiple assignments? Or at a single assignment of all students? Where are the documentation links you suggest you've found?

Comment: Here is the code to find grades

 var grades = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseid, assigid).studentSubmissions[n].assignedGrade;
    if(grades == undefined){grades = ""}

Comment: Edit your question so that you can properly present formatted code. Include any additional research results and attempts you have made.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should accomplish what you're trying to do. I've include course and courseWork creation first.

```
  course = {
    "name": "Course Title",
    "courseState": "ACTIVE",
    "ownerId": "me"
  }
  course = Classroom.Courses.create(course)
  courseWork = {
    "maxPoints": 25,
    "title": "CourseWork Title",
    "state": "PUBLISHED",
    "workType": "ASSIGNMENT"
  }
  courseWork = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, course.id)
  courseWorkDetails = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.get(courseId=course.id,
                                                       id=courseWork.id)
  maxPage = courseWorkDetails.maxPoints
  Logger.log(maxPage)
```